# Tengo estos códigos en mi blog y me han dejado de funcionar

Tags: javascript, html, css, script, slider

tengo los siguientes códigos y no sé por qué me han dejado de funcionar, ¿alguien me podría ayudar?
Hasta hace unos meses funcionaban sin problemas y de repente ya no.
Busqué este script

```
<div id="spylist"><script src="https://sites.google.com/site/unwanted86/javascript/animatedrecentpost.js" type="text/javascript"></script></div></center>
```

y me pone un mensaje de error.

> **Sitio no encontrado Lo sentimos, pero no hemos podido localizar el
> sitio que buscas.**

Entonces, ¿habría alguna forma de sustituir este script para que volviesen a funcionar?

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#PopularPosts1 {
overflow:hidden;
margin-top:5px;
width:93%;
padding:0px 8px 2px 5px;
height:475px;
}
#PopularPosts1 ul {
width:198px;
overflow:hidden;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px 1px 2px 1px;
margin:5px 0px 0px 1px;
}
#PopularPosts1 li {
 width:290px;
padding: 0px 1px 2px 1px;
margin:0px 0px 5px 0px;
list-style-type:none;
float:none;
height:80px;
overflow: hidden;
background: url(https://i.ibb.co/HdFRXXk/fono-fresita-by-annyz-blog-4.gif) repeat;
border:3px dotted #69e244;
border-radius: 15px;
}
#PopularPosts1 li .item-title {
    font-size:1em;
    margin-bottom:8px;
}
#PopularPosts1 li .item-title a {
text-decoration:none;
color: #fc812e;
font: 14px Elsie Swash Caps;
height:18px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 2px 0px;
}
#PopularPosts1 li img {
float: center;
margin-right: 0px;
border:3px dotted green;
border-radius: 15px;
}
#PopularPosts1 li .item-snippet {
  overflow:hidden;
font-family:Elsie,Arial,verdana, sans-serif;
font-size:10px;
color:#db5151;
padding:0px 0px;
margin:0px 0px;
}
#PopularPosts1 .item-snippet a,
#PopularPosts1 .item-snippet a:visited {
    color:#3E4548;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#PopularPosts1 .spyWrapper {
    height: 600%;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
}
#PopularPosts1 {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
.tags span,
.tags a {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
}
a img {
    border: 0;
}
-->
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function () {
    $('.popular-posts ul').simpleSpy();
});
</script>
<script src="http://accordion-for-blogger.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simplespy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<center><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
<!--
#spylist {
overflow:hidden;
margin-top: 5px;
padding:0px 0px;
height:450px;
}
#spylist ul{
width:196px;
overflow:hidden;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px 0px;
margin:0px 0px;
}
#spylist li {
-moz-border-radius: 15px;/**FORMA DEL RECUADRO EXTERIOR **/
border-radius: 15px;/** FORMA DEL RECUADRO EXTERIOR **/
width:174px;
padding: 5px 5px;
margin:0px 0px 5px 0px;
list-style-type:none;
float:none;
overflow: hidden;
background: url(https://i.ibb.co/PMRbNBJ/33-2.jpg) repeat;
border:1px dashed #ffb425;
}
#spylist li a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#69e244;/** COLOR DE TITULOS **/
font-size:16px;
height:18px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 2px 0px;
}
#spylist li img {
-moz-border-radius: 40px;/** FORMA DEL RECUADRO Y BORDE INTERIOR **/
border-radius: 40px;/** FORMA DEL RECUADRO Y BORDE INTERIOR **/
float:left;
margin-right: 5px;
background:url(url de tu imagen) repeat;
border:1px dashed #ffb425;/** FORMA DEL RECUADRO Y BORDE INTERIOR **/
}
.spydate{
overflow:hidden;
font-size:14px;
color:#d0a3ff;
padding:2px 0px;
margin:1px 0px 0px 0px;
height:15px;
font-family:Emilys Candy,Arial,verdana, sans-serif;
}
.spycomment{
overflow:hidden;
font-family:Emilys Candy,Arial,verdana, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color:#00a200;
padding:0px 0px;
margin:0px 0px;
}
--></style>
<script language="javascript">
imgr = new Array();
imgr[0] = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_CEj8AwvwSNM/TPkQUkM0wnI/AAAAAAAAFD8/TxYWe-CMPr8/s320/no_image.gif";
imgr[1] = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_CEj8AwvwSNM/TPkQUkM0wnI/AAAAAAAAFD8/TxYWe-CMPr8/s320/no_image.gif";
imgr[2] = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_CEj8AwvwSNM/TPkQUkM0wnI/AAAAAAAAFD8/TxYWe-CMPr8/s320/no_image.gif";
imgr[3] = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_CEj8AwvwSNM/TPkQUkM0wnI/AAAAAAAAFD8/TxYWe-CMPr8/s320/no_image.gif";
imgr[4] = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_CEj8AwvwSNM/TPkQUkM0wnI/AAAAAAAAFD8/TxYWe-CMPr8/s320/no_image.gif";
showRandomImg = true;
showRandomPosts = true;
boxwidth = 200;
cellspacing = 6;
borderColor = "#d34874";
bgTD = "#e49861";
thumbwidth = 70;
thumbheight = 70;
fntsize = 14;
acolor = "#9171b5";
aBold = true;
icon = " ";
text = "comments";
showPostDate = true;
summaryPost = 40;  /**Número de caracteres del resumen del post**/
summaryFontsize = 13;
summaryColor = "#fff";
icon2 = " ";
numposts = 10;  /**Número de entradas a mostrar**/
home_page = "https://litseycrazylovepersonaliza.blogspot.com/"; /** URL DE TU BLOG **/
limitspy=5
intervalspy=4000</script>
<div id="spylist"><script src="https://sites.google.com/site/unwanted86/javascript/animatedrecentpost.js" type="text/javascript"></script></div></center>
```

Comment: Parece que ya no dejaron publico el script. Lo respaldaste??

Comment: Busca el script "animatedrecentpost.js" pueda que ande por ahí en algún lado.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, tendrías que reemplazar el enlace caído del javascript animatedrecentpost.js por uno que subas tú al servidor donde tengas la web:

```
<div id="spylist"><script src="RUTA_AL_ARCHIVO_EN_TU_SERVIDOR/animatedrecentpost.js" type="text/javascript"></script></div></center>
```

He buscado el script y no aparece en ningún sitio, pero parece que en web.archive.org sí que lo puedes descargar: http://web.archive.org/web/20201012233651/https://26ed6613-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/unwanted86/javascript/animatedrecentpost.js?attachauth=ANoY7crqWcBxCVjRq2Za6gDGInrOqcfxTJ-Q1yqM4EadZcsUfXs-XuOhKMaD3EzCWdIBIKFKv9rh4imoS0elLvFNOZOet9_AET7Viozwkbr0MAnLaDHEn6THomC86vByZ1fVwqL7NerLMwhtQuXlau64pPA0_IJLCAkRK0_uyq4u2aKxjsIfG3mM_BZMpwl9lx-zOLDlIjUYuzT5P6BuefdthkDZqs3q9iTWBJhIUoHyCKqOv3rTd-k%3D&attredirects=0&d=1